# mod_pagespeed is rewriting but not combining

Tags: css, apache, mod-pagespeed

I have the following problem.

I installed mod_pagespeed but i am not getting the results i want!

It does rewrite my css and changes the  to the cache url but its not combining the css files.

I have seached the web and stackoverflow for it but did not find a solution.

Here are the  tags

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css.pagespeed.ce.Iz3TwZXylG.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/assets/css/W.jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css.pagespeed.cf.9yjmvb9yjz.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/assets/css/W.bootstrap.extend.css.pagespeed.cf.VelsS-YQRX.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/assets/css/W.base.css.pagespeed.cf.QO1yNADs1p.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://domain.com/assets/css/W.style.css.pagespeed.cf.tRzIhRbblc.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As requested:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you include rules you are using from your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: You have included only `mod_rewrite` rules, I'm more interested in `pagespeed_module` rules, have you set any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search in the error log there will probably be some information about why mod_pagespeed did not combine your resources (You may have to set Apache's `LogLevel info` temporarily). However, my guess is that some of the CSS files contained sections mod_pagespeed could not parse, and thus it could not safely combine the CSS files. This could be because they use unsupported CSS3 or proprietary CSS2 constructs. There's no way to know for sure without seeing the CSS files themselves. If you mail https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mod-pagespeed-discuss we can help figure out what's going on.

Comment: After much searching i think it has to do with the css i am using. Thanks for the information!